# Apache Flink DataStream - Count of Element in Tumbling Window

Tags: apache-flink, data-stream

I’m very new to Apache Flink and its API.I want to create Java program which will do event time based processing with tumbling windows. I want to count the number of elements in the given window. However, I couldn't figure how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

So, if you want to calculate the number of elements in window, probably the simplest idea is like this. Assuming you have `dataset` variable representing your dataset:

```
dataset.map(element => (element,1)).timeWindowAll(Time.seconds(5)).sum(1)
```

This should give you the number of elements in the window.